# How to debug rust web server in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, web, rust

I am building a web server using tide framework and I want to debug api function when server receive the request. However,when I click debug button on vs code, and using the curl command from terminal to send request to server, the terminal said "Failed to connect to port 3000,Connection refused". Does anyone know how to debug the rust web server on vscode?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue when I tried the code on this documentation page https://docs.rs/tide/latest/tide/. I'm going to assume that's what you're trying to debug?

I went to the github repository and there is a readme with a similar, but different example https://github.com/http-rs/tide. It works for me, and I could debug without any further issue using the rust-analyzer and CodeLLDB extensions.

Note: I had to restart my computer. After the first example failed I thought I'd try the curl command with a Node Express server to make sure there wasn't something blocking the request. After restarting this went away.